# Spyder Ipython console completely ignores print statements

Tags: python, ipython

After I did some upgrade, I noticed If I'm printing in a script or even in the console, nothing is shown. I even remember in a previous version (I did a lot of upgrades recently) there was a tab right next to Ipython where the print output was showing, but after upgrading Spyder, it's gone. I've also been getting a lot of kernel died, restarting, and it's been really close to unusable. I used to love spyder, now I waste too much time closing/restarting/resetting just to get my work done.

I'm using Anaconda 3.5.

And just while I was writing this post, a tab called "Internal console" just popped up from nowhere and tells me the following:

```
Spyder Internal Console

This console is used to report application
internal errors and to inspect Spyder
internals with the following commands:
  spy.app, spy.window, dir(spy)

Please don't use it to run your code

>>> WARNING:root:kernel died: 6.001342296600342
WARNING:root:kernel died: 6.000344276428223
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\console_widget.py", line 412, in eventFilter
    return self._event_filter_console_keypress(event)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 381, in _event_filter_console_keypress
    return super(FrontendWidget, self)._event_filter_console_keypress(event)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\console_widget.py", line 1130, in _event_filter_console_keypress
    self.copy()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\frontend_widget.py", line 249, in copy
        was_newline = text[-1] == '\n'
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: The current version of Anaconda is 4.3.1. Do you mean that you are using Python 3.5? Which version of Spyder are you using?

Comment: I have version 4.1.1 of Anaconda, and 3.1.1 py35 of spyder.

Comment: The latest version of Spyder is 3.1.3 with many bug fixes according to the [changelog](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). I'd recommend updating to the latest version of Spyder and testing again. If it still fails, please post the code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder lets you configure your run options.  You can run in an external console or in your current python or ipython console.  Maybe the default changed when you upgraded?
http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/blog/spyder-the-python-ide.html#run-settings

Comment: I just went back to version 2. If someone else is having this same problem, perhaps he could try your suggestion.